# How to dismiss a PopUp Menu when an Item Clicked in Android

Tags: android, select, popupmenu, dismiss

I am using popup menu in my code. It works perfectly . but when I select an item from it, menu was not dismissing .
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946797/dismiss-popup-when-options-menu-is-pressed)  . but it is not working

here is my code

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, edit1);
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
        popup.getMenu().add("one");
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // if (item.getTitle().equals("one")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        popup.dismiss();
        return false;
            }
        });
        //displaying the popup
        popup.show();
```

Please some one help me.

Comment: `return true;`, or move `popup.dismiss();` before return.

Comment: return true to your onMenuItemClick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this below code it will work for you

```
 popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // if (item.getTitle().equals("one")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                popup.dismiss();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

and as I see your comments if you are using **onTouchListener** for the EditText. just change it to **onClickListener** and your problem will be solved.

Comment: it is not working . again same issue  after clicking four times it is dismissing.

Comment: you need to put id in if else condition then it will work

Comment: can you give you menu.xml code in your question , so i can help you with appropriate code

Comment: My menu file is empty . I actually added menu items as  popup.getMenu().add("one");

Comment: I just debug my code, problem is from my side. don't know why my method caling 4 times .will check

Comment: check my updated answer , 
and as I see your comments if you are using **onTouchListener** for the EditText. just change it to onClickListener and your problem will be solved.

Comment: basha - onTouchListener responds for both landing and lifting , you need to replace it with onClickListener and then use the code as I written over here , it will solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163619/discussion-between-thunder-and-basha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163634/discussion-between-thunder-and-basha).

Answer (score 0):

This should be the code block. Returning `true` shows that the click was handled.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
   // if (item.getTitle().equals("one")) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return true;
}
```

Comment: not working. after clicking four times it is dismissing.

Comment: Then problem is somewhere else

Comment: actually Iam using onTouch listener of editText to display a menu

Comment: I just debug my code, problem is from my side. don't know why my method caling 4 times .will check