# Open custom menu on tap of option menu

Tags: android

I have activity with custom actionbar(Basically custom layout xml), therefore I have created a custom menu button as well in layout file and showing a popup,

I am usingthis callback to showing same popup on tap of hardware option menu, but give  a weird behaviour e.g this will open custom menu whenvery onresume is run.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        showHideMenu();
        return false;
    }
```

can you please suggest where I can place`showHideMenu();` will which work like custom option menu

```
//showHideMenu() code

private void showHideMenu() {
        if (mPopUpMenu.isShowing())
            dismissPopUpMenu();
        else
            showMenu();
    }

private void dismissPopUpMenu() {
        // dismiss menu
        if (mPopUpMenu != null)
            mPopUpMenu.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to link hardware menu button to actionbar menu ?

Comment: Yes Correct, I want to open same popup in hardware option menu which is open by actionbar menu,

Comment: you want to use `Hardware menu button` but in some devices it is not present , do have a second thought on how you will handle that ?

Comment: @Satyen It is present in all device, some devices have hard form and some devices have soft formlike home and back button, therefore callback and api are same for both.

Comment: @Lavekush kindly check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for an *up* keyevent:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        showHideMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Include this for PopUp:

```
mPopUpMenu.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {        
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                // ... payload action here. e.g. popupMenu.dismiss();
                return true;
            }                
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Reference:**
[Detecting physical Menu key press in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239880/detecting-physical-menu-key-press-in-android)

Comment: this is working fine, but when I press it again, this code does not trigger, it might be because a custom popup is showing that's why onKeyUp is not triggering again for hiding purposes.  have you any idea ?

Comment: may be you have not handled this case in showHideMenu();. Kindly post this function

Comment: I have handle but onKeyUp method is not triggering while any popup is displaying on the screen, and my menu is also a custom popup.

Comment: Added please have a look in question again

Comment: One more check, can you place a breakpoint and see if the function executes even if the popup is showing? I think somehow your instance of mPopUpMenu is getting null in dismissPopUpMenu()

Comment: I have allready did same things, that's why I inform you that code is not triggering due popup is displaying.and mPopUpMenu  is a have live instance, i have already cross all above points, thanks for your support, I think problem is that if any popup is displaying then keyUp event is not triggering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91354/discussion-between-shahzeb-and-lavekush).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PopupMenu` for showing custom menu.
for this you have to find a view to attach `menu`.and then you can wrote

```
 //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,popup.getMenu()); 
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
         public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          return true;  
         }  
        });  

        popup.show();//showing popup menu
```

for more information you can see http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Comment: I want to open this custom menu on tap of hardware option menu.

Comment: OP is little bit different please go through question again give a solution, this will not useful in my case